# Subgraph INDEXING ERROR: Error: failed to process trigger: block

Tags: web3js

I am getting an error when trying to synchronize a subgraph with the NftMarketplace.sol Smart Contract to listen for the events.

You can see my repos here:

- [Marketplace-backend](https://github.com/JMariadlcs/nft-marketplace-backend)
- [Marketplace-frontend](https://github.com/JMariadlcs/nft-marketplace-frontend-thegraph)
- [Graph repo](https://github.com/JMariadlcs/graph-nft-marketplace)

I am uploading a screenshot with the error that I am getting. I have followed every step on the tutorial and have tried to solve it in different ways but it did not work. I am out of ideas right now. You can check my repos in case you want to help me.[image]

I am posting some code from [Graph repo](https://github.com/JMariadlcs/graph-nft-marketplace):

- `src/nft-marketplace.ts`:

```bash
import { BigInt, Address } from "@graphprotocol/graph-ts";
import {
  NftMarketplace,
  ItemBought as ItemBoughtEvent,
  ItemCanceled as ItemCanceledEvent,
  ItemListed as ItemListedEvent
} from "../generated/NftMarketplace/NftMarketplace";
import {
  ItemListed,
  ActiveItem,
  ItemBought,
  ItemCanceled
} from "../generated/schema";

export function handleItemListed(event: ItemListedEvent): void {
  let itemListed = ItemListed.load(
    getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
  );
  let activeItem = ActiveItem.load(
    getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
  );
  if (!itemListed) {
    itemListed = new ItemListed(
      getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
    );
  }
  if (!activeItem) {
    activeItem = new ActiveItem(
      getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
    );
  }
  itemListed.seller = event.params.seller;
  activeItem.seller = event.params.seller;

  itemListed.nftAddress = event.params.nftAddress;
  activeItem.nftAddress = event.params.nftAddress;

  itemListed.tokenId = event.params.tokenId;
  activeItem.tokenId = event.params.tokenId;

  itemListed.price = event.params.price;
  activeItem.price = event.params.price;

  itemListed.save();
  activeItem.save();
}

export function handleItemCanceled(event: ItemCanceledEvent): void {
  let itemCanceled = ItemCanceled.load(
    getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
  );
  let activeItem = ActiveItem.load(
    getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
  );
  if (!itemCanceled) {
    itemCanceled = new ItemCanceled(
      getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
    );
  }
  itemCanceled.seller = event.params.seller;
  itemCanceled.nftAddress = event.params.nftAddress;
  itemCanceled.tokenId = event.params.tokenId;
  activeItem!.buyer = Address.fromString(
    "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD"
  );

  itemCanceled.save();
  activeItem!.save();
}

export function handleItemBought(event: ItemBoughtEvent): void {
  let itemBought = ItemBought.load(
    getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
  );
  let activeItem = ActiveItem.load(
    getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
  );
  if (!itemBought) {
    itemBought = new ItemBought(
      getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
    );
  }
  itemBought.buyer = event.params.buyer;
  itemBought.nftAddress = event.params.nftAddress;
  itemBought.tokenId = event.params.tokenId;
  activeItem!.buyer = event.params.buyer;

  itemBought.save();
  activeItem!.save();
}

function getIdFromEventParams(tokenId: BigInt, nftAddress: Address): string {
  return tokenId.toHexString() + nftAddress.toHexString();
}
```

- `generated/NftMarketplace/NftMarketplace.ts`:

```bash
// THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.

import {
  ethereum,
  JSONValue,
  TypedMap,
  Entity,
  Bytes,
  Address,
  BigInt
} from "@graphprotocol/graph-ts";

export class ItemBought extends ethereum.Event {
  get params(): ItemBought__Params {
    return new ItemBought__Params(this);
  }
}

export class ItemBought__Params {
  _event: ItemBought;

  constructor(event: ItemBought) {
    this._event = event;
  }

  get buyer(): Address {
    return this._event.parameters[0].value.toAddress();
  }

  get nftAddress(): Address {
    return this._event.parameters[1].value.toAddress();
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    return this._event.parameters[2].value.toBigInt();
  }

  get price(): BigInt {
    return this._event.parameters[3].value.toBigInt();
  }
}

export class ItemCanceled extends ethereum.Event {
  get params(): ItemCanceled__Params {
    return new ItemCanceled__Params(this);
  }
}

export class ItemCanceled__Params {
  _event: ItemCanceled;

  constructor(event: ItemCanceled) {
    this._event = event;
  }

  get seller(): Address {
    return this._event.parameters[0].value.toAddress();
  }

  get nftAddress(): Address {
    return this._event.parameters[1].value.toAddress();
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    return this._event.parameters[2].value.toBigInt();
  }
}

export class ItemListed extends ethereum.Event {
  get params(): ItemListed__Params {
    return new ItemListed__Params(this);
  }
}

export class ItemListed__Params {
  _event: ItemListed;

  constructor(event: ItemListed) {
    this._event = event;
  }

  get seller(): Address {
    return this._event.parameters[0].value.toAddress();
  }

  get nftAddress(): Address {
    return this._event.parameters[1].value.toAddress();
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    return this._event.parameters[2].value.toBigInt();
  }

  get price(): BigInt {
    return this._event.parameters[3].value.toBigInt();
  }
}

export class NftMarketplace__getListingResultValue0Struct extends ethereum.Tuple {
  get price(): BigInt {
    return this[0].toBigInt();
  }

  get seller(): Address {
    return this[1].toAddress();
  }
}

export class NftMarketplace extends ethereum.SmartContract {
  static bind(address: Address): NftMarketplace {
    return new NftMarketplace("NftMarketplace", address);
  }

  getListing(
    nftAddress: Address,
    tokenId: BigInt
  ): NftMarketplace__getListingResultValue0Struct {
    let result = super.call(
      "getListing",
      "getListing(address,uint256):((uint256,address))",
      [
        ethereum.Value.fromAddress(nftAddress),
        ethereum.Value.fromUnsignedBigInt(tokenId)
      ]
    );

    return changetype<NftMarketplace__getListingResultValue0Struct>(
      result[0].toTuple()
    );
  }

  try_getListing(
    nftAddress: Address,
    tokenId: BigInt
  ): ethereum.CallResult<NftMarketplace__getListingResultValue0Struct> {
    let result = super.tryCall(
      "getListing",
      "getListing(address,uint256):((uint256,address))",
      [
        ethereum.Value.fromAddress(nftAddress),
        ethereum.Value.fromUnsignedBigInt(tokenId)
      ]
    );
    if (result.reverted) {
      return new ethereum.CallResult();
    }
    let value = result.value;
    return ethereum.CallResult.fromValue(
      changetype<NftMarketplace__getListingResultValue0Struct>(
        value[0].toTuple()
      )
    );
  }

  getProceeds(seller: Address): BigInt {
    let result = super.call("getProceeds", "getProceeds(address):(uint256)", [
      ethereum.Value.fromAddress(seller)
    ]);

    return result[0].toBigInt();
  }

  try_getProceeds(seller: Address): ethereum.CallResult<BigInt> {
    let result = super.tryCall(
      "getProceeds",
      "getProceeds(address):(uint256)",
      [ethereum.Value.fromAddress(seller)]
    );
    if (result.reverted) {
      return new ethereum.CallResult();
    }
    let value = result.value;
    return ethereum.CallResult.fromValue(value[0].toBigInt());
  }
}

export class BuyItemCall extends ethereum.Call {
  get inputs(): BuyItemCall__Inputs {
    return new BuyItemCall__Inputs(this);
  }

  get outputs(): BuyItemCall__Outputs {
    return new BuyItemCall__Outputs(this);
  }
}

export class BuyItemCall__Inputs {
  _call: BuyItemCall;

  constructor(call: BuyItemCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }

  get nftAddress(): Address {
    return this._call.inputValues[0].value.toAddress();
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    return this._call.inputValues[1].value.toBigInt();
  }
}

export class BuyItemCall__Outputs {
  _call: BuyItemCall;

  constructor(call: BuyItemCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }
}

export class CancelListingCall extends ethereum.Call {
  get inputs(): CancelListingCall__Inputs {
    return new CancelListingCall__Inputs(this);
  }

  get outputs(): CancelListingCall__Outputs {
    return new CancelListingCall__Outputs(this);
  }
}

export class CancelListingCall__Inputs {
  _call: CancelListingCall;

  constructor(call: CancelListingCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }

  get nftAddress(): Address {
    return this._call.inputValues[0].value.toAddress();
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    return this._call.inputValues[1].value.toBigInt();
  }
}

export class CancelListingCall__Outputs {
  _call: CancelListingCall;

  constructor(call: CancelListingCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }
}

export class ListItemCall extends ethereum.Call {
  get inputs(): ListItemCall__Inputs {
    return new ListItemCall__Inputs(this);
  }

  get outputs(): ListItemCall__Outputs {
    return new ListItemCall__Outputs(this);
  }
}

export class ListItemCall__Inputs {
  _call: ListItemCall;

  constructor(call: ListItemCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }

  get nftAddress(): Address {
    return this._call.inputValues[0].value.toAddress();
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    return this._call.inputValues[1].value.toBigInt();
  }

  get price(): BigInt {
    return this._call.inputValues[2].value.toBigInt();
  }
}

export class ListItemCall__Outputs {
  _call: ListItemCall;

  constructor(call: ListItemCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }
}

export class UpdateListingCall extends ethereum.Call {
  get inputs(): UpdateListingCall__Inputs {
    return new UpdateListingCall__Inputs(this);
  }

  get outputs(): UpdateListingCall__Outputs {
    return new UpdateListingCall__Outputs(this);
  }
}

export class UpdateListingCall__Inputs {
  _call: UpdateListingCall;

  constructor(call: UpdateListingCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }

  get nftAddress(): Address {
    return this._call.inputValues[0].value.toAddress();
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    return this._call.inputValues[1].value.toBigInt();
  }

  get newPrice(): BigInt {
    return this._call.inputValues[2].value.toBigInt();
  }
}

export class UpdateListingCall__Outputs {
  _call: UpdateListingCall;

  constructor(call: UpdateListingCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }
}

export class WithdrawProceedsCall extends ethereum.Call {
  get inputs(): WithdrawProceedsCall__Inputs {
    return new WithdrawProceedsCall__Inputs(this);
  }

  get outputs(): WithdrawProceedsCall__Outputs {
    return new WithdrawProceedsCall__Outputs(this);
  }
}

export class WithdrawProceedsCall__Inputs {
  _call: WithdrawProceedsCall;

  constructor(call: WithdrawProceedsCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }
}

export class WithdrawProceedsCall__Outputs {
  _call: WithdrawProceedsCall;

  constructor(call: WithdrawProceedsCall) {
    this._call = call;
  }
}
```

- `generated/schema.ts`:

```bash
// THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.

import {
  TypedMap,
  Entity,
  Value,
  ValueKind,
  store,
  Bytes,
  BigInt,
  BigDecimal
} from "@graphprotocol/graph-ts";

export class ActiveItem extends Entity {
  constructor(id: string) {
    super();
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(id));
  }

  save(): void {
    let id = this.get("id");
    assert(id != null, "Cannot save ActiveItem entity without an ID");
    if (id) {
      assert(
        id.kind == ValueKind.STRING,
        `Entities of type ActiveItem must have an ID of type String but the id '${id.displayData()}' is of type ${id.displayKind()}`
      );
      store.set("ActiveItem", id.toString(), this);
    }
  }

  static load(id: string): ActiveItem | null {
    return changetype<ActiveItem | null>(store.get("ActiveItem", id));
  }

  get id(): string {
    let value = this.get("id");
    return value!.toString();
  }

  set id(value: string) {
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(value));
  }

  get buyer(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("buyer");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set buyer(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("buyer", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get seller(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("seller");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set seller(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("seller", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get nftAddress(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("nftAddress");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set nftAddress(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("nftAddress", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    let value = this.get("tokenId");
    return value!.toBigInt();
  }

  set tokenId(value: BigInt) {
    this.set("tokenId", Value.fromBigInt(value));
  }

  get price(): BigInt | null {
    let value = this.get("price");
    if (!value || value.kind == ValueKind.NULL) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return value.toBigInt();
    }
  }

  set price(value: BigInt | null) {
    if (!value) {
      this.unset("price");
    } else {
      this.set("price", Value.fromBigInt(<BigInt>value));
    }
  }
}

export class ItemListed extends Entity {
  constructor(id: string) {
    super();
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(id));
  }

  save(): void {
    let id = this.get("id");
    assert(id != null, "Cannot save ItemListed entity without an ID");
    if (id) {
      assert(
        id.kind == ValueKind.STRING,
        `Entities of type ItemListed must have an ID of type String but the id '${id.displayData()}' is of type ${id.displayKind()}`
      );
      store.set("ItemListed", id.toString(), this);
    }
  }

  static load(id: string): ItemListed | null {
    return changetype<ItemListed | null>(store.get("ItemListed", id));
  }

  get id(): string {
    let value = this.get("id");
    return value!.toString();
  }

  set id(value: string) {
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(value));
  }

  get seller(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("seller");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set seller(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("seller", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get nftAddress(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("nftAddress");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set nftAddress(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("nftAddress", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    let value = this.get("tokenId");
    return value!.toBigInt();
  }

  set tokenId(value: BigInt) {
    this.set("tokenId", Value.fromBigInt(value));
  }

  get price(): BigInt | null {
    let value = this.get("price");
    if (!value || value.kind == ValueKind.NULL) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return value.toBigInt();
    }
  }

  set price(value: BigInt | null) {
    if (!value) {
      this.unset("price");
    } else {
      this.set("price", Value.fromBigInt(<BigInt>value));
    }
  }
}

export class ItemCanceled extends Entity {
  constructor(id: string) {
    super();
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(id));
  }

  save(): void {
    let id = this.get("id");
    assert(id != null, "Cannot save ItemCanceled entity without an ID");
    if (id) {
      assert(
        id.kind == ValueKind.STRING,
        `Entities of type ItemCanceled must have an ID of type String but the id '${id.displayData()}' is of type ${id.displayKind()}`
      );
      store.set("ItemCanceled", id.toString(), this);
    }
  }

  static load(id: string): ItemCanceled | null {
    return changetype<ItemCanceled | null>(store.get("ItemCanceled", id));
  }

  get id(): string {
    let value = this.get("id");
    return value!.toString();
  }

  set id(value: string) {
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(value));
  }

  get seller(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("seller");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set seller(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("seller", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get nftAddress(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("nftAddress");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set nftAddress(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("nftAddress", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    let value = this.get("tokenId");
    return value!.toBigInt();
  }

  set tokenId(value: BigInt) {
    this.set("tokenId", Value.fromBigInt(value));
  }
}

export class ItemBought extends Entity {
  constructor(id: string) {
    super();
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(id));
  }

  save(): void {
    let id = this.get("id");
    assert(id != null, "Cannot save ItemBought entity without an ID");
    if (id) {
      assert(
        id.kind == ValueKind.STRING,
        `Entities of type ItemBought must have an ID of type String but the id '${id.displayData()}' is of type ${id.displayKind()}`
      );
      store.set("ItemBought", id.toString(), this);
    }
  }

  static load(id: string): ItemBought | null {
    return changetype<ItemBought | null>(store.get("ItemBought", id));
  }

  get id(): string {
    let value = this.get("id");
    return value!.toString();
  }

  set id(value: string) {
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(value));
  }

  get buyer(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("buyer");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set buyer(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("buyer", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get nftAddress(): Bytes {
    let value = this.get("nftAddress");
    return value!.toBytes();
  }

  set nftAddress(value: Bytes) {
    this.set("nftAddress", Value.fromBytes(value));
  }

  get tokenId(): BigInt {
    let value = this.get("tokenId");
    return value!.toBigInt();
  }

  set tokenId(value: BigInt) {
    this.set("tokenId", Value.fromBigInt(value));
  }

  get price(): BigInt | null {
    let value = this.get("price");
    if (!value || value.kind == ValueKind.NULL) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return value.toBigInt();
    }
  }

  set price(value: BigInt | null) {
    if (!value) {
      this.unset("price");
    } else {
      this.set("price", Value.fromBigInt(<BigInt>value));
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in

> src/nft-marketplace.ts

you need to assign the null address to the *activeItem.buyer* in *handleItemListed()* function.

just add :

```
activeItem!.buyer = Address.fromString("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
```